# No warning for unused import

Tags: java, gradle, compiler-errors

I am building a gradle java project using sublime, instead of an IDE like eclipse. I have notice when I run the build task, I do not get any warnings about unused imports.

Is there a compiler option in java that can turn on my strict warnings? If so, how do I enable that in my build.gradle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Warning on unused imports is not something the Java compiler currently handles: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/javac.html#examples-of-using--xlint-keys

You can use an external code style tool to take care of that for you. For example, with [Spotless](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/master/plugin-gradle)

```
plugins {
    `java`
    id("com.diffplug.gradle.spotless") version "4.0.0"
}

spotless {
    java {
        eclipse()
        removeUnusedImports()
        trimTrailingWhitespace()
        endWithNewline()
    }
}
```

and the following Java source with unused `List` import:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

when I try to build the project, I will immediately get an error:

```
> Task :build FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:spotlessJava'.
> The following files had format violations:
      src\main\java\io\mateo\gradle\build\Example.java
          @@ -1,7 +1,5 @@
           package╖io.mateo.gradle.build;

          -import╖java.util.List;
          -
           public╖class╖Example╖{

           \tpublic╖static╖void╖main(String[]╖args)╖{
  Run 'gradlew spotlessApply' to fix these violations.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Unfortunately sublime does not support multiple regex for jumping to errors in the build output. So the different output format of spotless wont work for my specific use case :(